# Why GetDC returns different values for the same object?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using this code to get the `Device Context` (aka DC) of the object / window at the current mouse position.

```
POINT curPos;

while (1)
{
    GetCursorPos(&curPos);
    printf("hdc: %ld\n", GetDC(WindowFromPoint(curPos)));
    Sleep(300);
}
```

After compiling and executing, I place the mouse on the console and leave it there, without moving it, and always prints a different value (also negative numbers). For example:

```
hdc: -1795094423
hdc: -1425992173
hdc: 1090588133
hdc: 553717209
hdc: 1979782668
hdc: 2013337074
hdc: -1241444488
```

I know I can use `GetWindowDC` go get the `DC` of a specific window, but I want to get the `DC` of specific parts of that window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that the window is defined to use a common DC that is pooled, so GetDC() is returning a different DC each time it is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this happens with all windows, also the desktop.

Comment: It should not if a given window is defined to use a class DC or a private DC, in which case GetDC() would return the same DC each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't generally be retrieving a bunch of HDC's over and over again without releasing any of them. Try releasing them before grabbing another and see what happens.

At any rate, there's no reason that they would be the same. In fact, the way you're doing it, without releasing them, they would have to be different numbers since each one is a handle to a different object.

As for the numbers being "negative", that's of no importance at all. They should really be printed as hex.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  POINT curPos;
  while (1)
  {
    GetCursorPos(&curPos);
    HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(curPos);
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    printf("hdc: %08lX\n", (unsigned long)hdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    Sleep(1000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point about releasing, I did not notice that.  If a window uses a class DC or a private DC, it does not need to be released, but then GetDC() would return the same HDC each time.  But if the window is using a common DC then it is pulled from a system pool, so releasing is important, otherwise GetDC() has to pull a different HDC each time since the earlier HDCs are still being used.

Comment: Yes, releasing was the trick. I tried this, and works, but for the same object it prints a number for the first 2 seconds and then it prints another for ever. Can you try this code and tell me if you see the same behaviour? Edit: Now that I run this again, the number changes every time I set the cursor on a window and then go back to the original.

Comment: @cdonts The numeric value of a DC is not significant. You shouldn't care whether a DC happens to have the same numeric value as an earlier DC.

Comment: Well, but if I want to draw something there I have to be sure that it won't change in the next 5 seconds. Btw, this answer solve my specific question so I'll accept it. Thanks a lot both of you for your help.

Comment: for the printf since handles are pointers `printf("hdc: %p\n", hdc);`